# How to display results from a database from newest to oldest

Tags: php

I have a page that displays entered data from a database in a table. I am wondering how I can reverse the order displayed from newest to oldest.

Here is the code for the fetch page that displays my results in the table, html has been removed as it is irrelevant to the question.

```
<?php 

    // Create connection in mysqli
    $connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);

    //Check connection in mysqli
    if($connection->connect_error) {
        die("Error on connection:" .$connection->connect_error);
    }

    //Display the informaion
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM logs";
    $res = $connection->query($sql);
    if($res->num_rows > 0) {
       // echo table row code
       while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
           // echo table row code 
       } 
    }
    else {
         echo "No Record Found!";
    }

    $connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY id DESC"; - That is if your primary key is id in the database

Comment: Do you have to order it from a date contained in your table, or by insert order?

Comment: What have you tried? I believe you could just add ORDER BY parameter to your $sql variable to sort by the given field.

Comment: e ec ech echo!..

Answer (score 1):

Simply modify your query like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY `column` DESC";
```

Where `column` is your column with the primary key. Normaly it is ID or id...

Comment: tried this error i get is            

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\database\hysteryalelogs\fetch.php on line 15
No Record Found!

Comment: LOL nevermind. I forgot to change the ID lol. Thanks guys it worked